# How do I find Mediawiki OAUTH callback URL (node passport-mediawiki-oauth)

Tags: oauth, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get my node webpage to authenticate against our internal mediawiki system, and wen't down the route of using the node passport-mediawiki-oauth.

Think it is all correctly set up, I get as far as being forwarded to the mediawiki login page, provide login details, then get a "Unknown URL, E003" from mediawiki (onscreen, rather than a return code). My problem is, I can not figure out what could be causing this issue.

I have tried setting the callbackURL (http://127.0.0.1:30005/auth/mediawiki/callback), I have tried leaving it blank to use the one that is set by default (same one as above provided in the proposal for the Oauth on mediawiki).

I would investigate further, but I have put on the mediawiki debug, no information. I have tried to find information on issue E003, no information. If I at least can figure out what URL its trying to use for the feedback to see if that is the issue, but I am completely stuck.

The configuration for passport-mediawiki-oauth is (Sensitive information removed):

```
consumerKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
consumerSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:30005/auth/mediawiki/callback",
requestTokenURL: 'http://192.168.0.51:8081/dbfswiki/index.php?title=Special:OAuth/initiate',
accessTokenURL: 'http://192.168.0.51:8081/dbfswiki/index.php?title=Special%3AOAuth%2Ftoken',
userAuthorizationURL: 'http://192.168.0.51:8081/dbfswiki//wiki/Special:OAuth/authorize',
baseURL: "http://192.168.0.51:8081/dbfswiki/index.php/Special:OAuth/authorize"
```

And the code for the authentication is handled by this:

```
passport.use('mediawiki', new MediaWikiStrategy({
        consumerKey: configAuth.mediawikiAuth.consumerKey,
        consumerSecret: configAuth.mediawikiAuth.consumerSecret ,
        callbackURL: configAuth.mediawikiAuth.callbackURL,
        baseURL: configAuth.mediawikiAuth.baseURL
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({ mediawikiGlobalId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: [The OAuth MediaWiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth) requires you to specify the callback URL, or at least a prefix of it (such as the domain name) in advance, as a security measure. So you need to register a new consumer in MediaWiki, set the callback URL there and then make sure your node module either sends a matching callback URL or nothing. Feel free to [file a bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/create/?projects=mediawiki-extensions-oauth) if you have suggestions on how to make the error message more useful.

Answer (score 0):

So one step forward (one step back). After much fiddling about I think I found the issue. Where as I thought it was the callback URL that was the issue, it turns out it was the authorisation URL that was wrong. passport-mediawiki-oauth seems to have added the OAuth twice/dbfswiki/**index.php/Special:OAuth/authorize**wiki/*Special:OAuth/authorize*?oauth_token=&oauth_consumer_key=449c71620457972e86ef20e083ccb87bFixed this in the module code, only to be faced with a new issue, I know get a accept box, (application ... wants basic rights, and when I press OK, I get a There is problem with your input)

Comment: token is missing in url: oauth_token=&oauth_consumer_key